# Can Paket resolve packages from different sources?

Tags: nuget, paket

I have local nuget repository nuget.companyrepo.com. I publish SuperLibrary to that repo. This library has dependency in paket.template like that:

```
dependencies
    Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.1
files
    build/SuperLibrary.dll => lib
```

In my second project I'm creating paket.dependencies file:

```
content: none
framework: = net40
source https://nuget.org/api/v2
source https://nuget.companyrepo.com

nuget log4net
nuget SuperLibrary
```

And when I update paket I have a message that:

Failed to getDetailsFromNuGetViaOdataFast 'https://nuget.companyrepo.com/api/nuget/Packages?$filter=tolower((Id) eq 'newtonsoft.json')"... The remote server returned an error: (405) Method not Allowed.

So paket is looking for SuperLibrary related dependencies only in its repository. I want Paket to pull this dependency from nuget.org. I don't want to copy all dependencies of my dependencies!

How can I solve that!?